# Detecting characters batch sript

Tags: batch-file

I have a script which is renaming and moving files to folder by detecting its character based on `_` delimeter and the numbers listed below.

> 631598_S_14CG_Layout-1.pdf
>   631598_1_Barcode.pdf
>   631598_001_CutData.ppf

Output folder should be `631598_S_1`

> 631598_S_14CGBarcode.pdf
>   631598_001_CutData.ppf

Output folder should be `631598_S_2`

> 631598_S_14CG_Layout-11.pdf
>   631598_11_Barcode.pdf
>   631598_011_CutData.ppf

Output folder should be `631598_S_11`

> 631598_S_14CG_Layout-22.pdf
>   631598_22_Barcode.pdf
>   631598_22_CutData.ppf

Output folder should be `631598_S_22`

But the thing is I am on only detecting 10 characters and so all those who has the same 10th charater moved to the same folder for example:

> 631598_S_14CG_Layout-22.pdf
>   631598_22_Barcode.pdf
>   631598_22_CutData.ppf

…will move to `631598_S_2` and not `631598_S_22`

Below is the script

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "Pattern=_Layout-"
set "Replace=_"

for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    set "File=%%~a"
    ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do ren "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d.pdf" "%%a_%%b_%%d.pdf"

pushd ."\*"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.pdf ^|findstr /v "Barcode"') do (
  2>nul md "%%~nF"

)

TIMEOUT /T 01

set "Pattern1=_00"
set "Replace1=_S_"

for %%a in (*.ppf) do (
    set "File=%%~a"
    ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern1%=%Replace1%!"
)

set "Pattern2=_0"
set "Replace2=_S_"

for %%a in (*.ppf) do (
    set "File=%%~a"
    ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern2%=%Replace2%!"
)

set "Pattern3=Cut Data"
set "Replace3=CutData"

for %%a in (*.ppf) do (
    set "File=%%~a"
    ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern3%=%Replace3%!"
)

set "Pattern=_Barcode"
set "Replace=_Barcode_S"

for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    set "File=%%~a"
    ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do ren "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d.pdf" "%%a_%%d_%%b_%%c.pdf"


for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /a-d /b *.pdf *.ppf') do (
    set filename=%%1&set dirname=!filename:~0,10!

        for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /ad /b') do (
        set dirid=%%A&set dirid=!dirid:~0,10!

        if "!dirid!" equ "!dirname!" move %%1 %%A

  )   
)
```

Comment: You would need to explain precisely how the directoryname is derived from the filename.

Comment: Why did you abandon your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887958/batch-process-auto-foldering) about this very same question.  I was willing to help you but if you aren't going to answer my questions or provide information in the way it needs to be it makes it very difficult to help you.

Comment: Your first two examples contradict each other.